# How to let the path of a composition shine to parent layer?

Tags: after-effects

I added some point lights that form a letter. Then I added an optical flare (AE plugin FX) with source type "track lights" to get light dots from the light layers.

This works fine and looks as follows:

```
optical flare layer FX
light layer1 (point)
light layer2 (point)
light layerN (point)
```

Now I of course want to create several letters. Therefore I group the light layers each in a composition that represents a letter. Of course I do not want to dublicate the optical flare layer into all my compositions, but move it out and just have one flare layer that is FX for all lights:

```
[optical flare layer FX]
[light composition A]
[light composition B]
[light composition C]
```

Problem: As soon as I move the optical layer out of the light compositions, the FX is not applied anymore to the lights that are contained inside the multiple compositions.

Why? How can I let the light layers of my compositions "shine through" to the parent layer, and apply the flare FX there with only one single FX layer?

Comment: have you tried turning on continuously rasterise / collapse transformations (the little sun icon) for the light comps. Also, you know there are other ways of getting glowing light effects without using actual lights, don't you?

Comment: No I don't, can you give me some keywords? I tried rasterise, but that won't work as the optical flare FX requires the lights to be in the same composition than the FX layer itself.

Comment: Are the light comps 3D layers (as well as collapsed)? As for other glowing lights, the good ol' glow effect works well on bright coloured layers. You could create a shape layer and use a dotted stroke, and apply the glow effect. Or an adjustment layer with a blur effect on it set to additive mode.